# sphinxql query mysql

Tags: sql, sphinx

How to use such a query in sphinx via sphinxql ?

```
SELECT t1.value_id, t1.option_id, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.product_id) AS total 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t11 ON (oov2p.product_id = oov2p1.product_id) 
WHERE t11.option_id = 10012 AND t11.value_id IN (456105035,2199381524) 
GROUP BY t1.option_id, t1.value_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx doesn't support joins, so there's no easy way to run this query in Sphinx.

Comment: Is there any plan to support Joins in Manticore?

Comment: Working on it - https://github.com/manticoresoftware/manticoresearch/issues/1673

Comment: Done in https://github.com/manticoresoftware/manticoresearch/pull/1855

Answer (score 0):

Well, while sphinx itself cant run 'join' queries between muitiple indexes.

You can use a 'JOIN' in the 'sql_query', so can create a sphinx index that is 'prejoined' so could run a query like that.

```
source  mysource {
   ...
   sql_query = 
      SELECT t1.product_id, t1.value_id, t11.option_id, GROUP_CONCAT(t11.value_id) as t11ids
      FROM table1 t1
      LEFT JOIN table1 t11 USING (product_id) 
      GROUP BY product_id

  sql_attr_uint = option_id
  sql_attr_multi =  uint t11ids from field
```

Which would then allow you to run a sphinxQL query somewhat like....

```
sphinxQL> SELECT id, option_id, COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) AS total
FROM myindex
WHERE option_id = 10012 AND t11ids IN (456105035,2199381524) 
GROUP BY option_id;
```

I've simplified the exact attributes saved, Your example query is a bit confusing with value and option_ids from mulitple tables.
.. so its only to sort of demonstrates the conscept, rather than a full example.

The key point is you store any columns you want to filter or 'group by' (or order!) as actual **Attributes** in the index, then can use them in the sphinxql query!

*(note the use of the special Multi-Value-Attribute (mva), this is a concept pretty unique to Sphinx where mutiple values are stored in one row, like the output of GROUP_CONCAT(). but allows pretty complex indexes, when the source tables are a one-to-many relatioship, stores values from the 'many' side)*